# Active_admin's devise i18n translate is uncomplete,where is the right resource?

Tags: devise, activeadmin

Though there are some translate here:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/locales

But it's uncomplete about devise.

Where can I find a best resource with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow this:

```
$ cd config/locales && wget https://raw.github.com/diaspora/diaspora/master/config/locales/devise/devise.en.yml
$ wget https://raw.github.com/diaspora/diaspora/master/config/locales/devise/devise.fr.yml
```

## Création d'une application rubyonrails avec Devise CanCan et ActiveAdmin

http://blog.escarworld.com/post/2011/09/23/Cr%C3%A9ation-d-une-application-rubyonrails-avec-Devise-CanCan-et-ActiveAdmin